# How to add an authentication layer to Docker REST API?

Tags: docker, rest, oauth-2.0, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am trying to connect to docker daemon through a tcp port using REST API remotely. Currently anyone can access it through the endpoint. How can I make it secured with Oauth or ID/Password?

Comment: The only thing in standard Docker is TLS client certificate authorization.  I'd really recommend not enabling this at all, and either using `ssh root@host ...` or an automation tool like Ansible, Chef, or Salt Stack; it's very easy to use Docker to take over a host and you don't want to accidentally get the authentication setup wrong.

Comment: Then how does portainer use an authentication method? I think there should be a workaround at-least.

Answer (score 1):

you can try ORY
https://github.com/ory/hydra

for more info, https://www.ory.sh/hydra/docs/configure-deploy/#installing-ory-hydra

ORY Hydra: OAuth2 & OpenID Connect Server
ORY Hydra is an OpenID Certified™ OAuth2 and OpenID Connect Provider can connect to any existing identity database (LDAP, AD, KeyCloak, PHP+MySQL, ...) and user interface.

ORY Oathkeeper: Identity & Access Proxy
ORY Oathkeeper is a BeyondCorp/Zero Trust Identity & Access Proxy (IAP) with configurable authentication, authorization, and request mutation rules for your web services: Authenticate JWT, Access Tokens, API Keys, mTLS; Check if the contained subject is allowed to perform the request; Encode resulting content into custom headers (X-User-ID), JSON Web Tokens and more!